# How to set up a MySQL trigger to update another tables columns?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to triggers. I have two tables - dataTable and infoTable. Both have a related row generated at the same time and are linked by common field. Like this:

```
infoTable
appNo | appID | appKey | appName | dateStarted | lastModified | status | reference

dataTable
appID | userID| appNo | appKey | appName | reference | status | dateStarted | lastModified
```

The dataTable is updated frequently throughout the front facing form being filled out, by AJAX. The infoTable is not touched by the form being filled out, so I need the "status", "reference" and "lastModified" fields from the dataTable to be updated to the infoTable after each AJAX update call. Both tables share a common and unique appID.

I have tried the following so far, without success.

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_sync AFTER INSERT ON dataTable
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE records r
SET r.reference    = NEW.reference
  , r.status       = NEW.status
  , r.lastModified = NEW.lastModified
WHERE r.appID = NEW.appID;
```

While MySQL seems to accept the syntax as a trigger, it breaks the functional system and fails to do it's objective. Can someone help me with the trigger syntax to get it to work please?

Comment: You aren't referencing infoTable at all in the trigger.  I am no expert, but that doesn't seem right.  Also, you mention **updating** the dataTable, yet your trigger is on `INSERT`.

Comment: @steveklein Yes I see what you mean, I've just been trying to put together something from what I have read and researched but I've failed to find an example that directly relates to what I am wanting. Hence me asking here. :)

Comment: If this is just a trigger to update infoTable whenever dataTable is updated, wouldn't the example in http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php work?  2nd Google result on "mysql update trigger".

Comment: No, this does not show me how to update an entry in the infoTable, it shows how to create a new entry. I need to update the existing corresponding entry after finding it by appID and how to differentiate updating it to new values as taken from the dataTable. Entirely different process.

Comment: Also the search for "mysql update trigger" could be a bad way to search as it can also bring up results on how to simply update any trigger in mysql, not necessarily create the specific type of update trigger. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the question as no functional answer was returned. Have given up using triggers (they seem a bit unpredictable anyway) and gone back to handling everything with php. Perhaps the slightly longer winded way, but seems the most reliable method.